# How to replace DOUBLE_QUOTE " Character in uipath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I am new to UIPath and having too trouble in replacing Double quotes, can anyone please help?

Comment: What is a double quote for you? Please paste an example.

Answer (score 1):

I stored the DOUBLE_QUOTE in a variable using ASCII conversion and then passed that variable into replace method.

Please let me know if any easier solution is there.

Comment: Could you help to share your data in the variable, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a double quote in a string constant simple duplicate it, ie. `"Quotes" as escaped by doubling them` would look like `""Quotes"" as escaped by doubling them`

Answer (score 1):

your solution is quite good but you can use: `string = string.ToString.Replace(""""," ")`

Answer (score 0):

For using double quotes in a string you can use chr() function as "leftPartOfString"+CHR(34).toString+"RightPartOfString".

And for Replacing inputString.Replace(chr(34).toString,"").TY.